# oauth redirecting in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I will try to implement redirect with oauth authorization in asp.net mvc4 project

**controller**

```
public ActionResult SomeName() {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { provider = "vkontakte" });
            }
}
```

**account**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider) {
            return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"));
        }
```

**error**

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its 
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
unavailable.  
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Account/ExternalLogin
```

Does anybody know what I should to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider) {
        return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `RedirectToAction` you are making a GET request to the url of your action, you need to accept `HttpGet` at `ExternalLogin` action on your `AccountController`

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToAction is 302 redirect request which is GET by nature. if you are supposed to utilize your action from VIEW as well, you can use both verbs :

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost]
```

Answer (score 0):

at ExternalLogin action on your AccountController accept HttpGet as other member also said.